# Use SED or AWK to find and replace string across multiple lines

Tags: awk, sed, accessibility

I have an HTML file that contains a string on one line that I would like to move to another line after a string.

The command would need to take into account variations of the first string across the document.

I have tried the following with Sed, but they don't work:

```
sed 's/\(aria-describedby="page-[0-9]"\)\(.*<aside \)/\2\1/g'
```

and

```
 sed 's/\(aria-describedby="page-[0-9]"\)\(.*<aside \)/\2\1/g'
```

The string that I would like to find is `aria-describedby="page-foo"` and I would like to move this string after strings that begin with `<aside` before the next instance of `aria-describedby="page-foo"`.

Input:

```
<h6 aria-describedby="page-1" id="page-1">Page 1</h6>
<h1 id="chapter-1">Chapter 1</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<h2 id="math-content">Math Content</h2>
<p><span class="math display">\[\sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}\]</span></p>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<aside role="doc-footnote">
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
</aside>
<aside role="complementary">
<p>Secondary Text Begin:</p>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<p>Secondary Text End</p>
</aside>
<h6 aria-describedby="page-2" id="page-2">Page 2</h6>
<h1 id="chapter-2">Chapter 2</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<h2 id="math-content">Math Content</h2>
<p><span class="math display">\[\sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}\]</span></p>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<aside role="doc-footnote">
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
</aside>
<aside role="complementary">
<p>Secondary Text Begin:</p>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<p>Secondary Text End</p>
</aside>
```

Desired Output:

```
<h6 id="page-1">Page 1</h6>
<h1 id="chapter-1">Chapter 1</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<h2 id="math-content">Math Content</h2>
<p><span class="math display">\[\sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}\]</span></p>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<aside aria-describedby="page-1" role="doc-footnote">
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
</aside>
<aside aria-describedby="page-1" role="complementary">
<p>Secondary Text Begin:</p>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<p>Secondary Text End</p>
</aside>
<h6 id="page-2">Page 2</h6>
<h1 id="chapter-2">Chapter 2</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<h2 id="math-content">Math Content</h2>
<p><span class="math display">\[\sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}\]</span></p>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<aside aria-describedby="page-2" role="doc-footnote">
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
</aside>
<aside aria-describedby="page-2" role="complementary">
<p>Secondary Text Begin:</p>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<p>Secondary Text End</p>
</aside>
```

Comment: are you sure you want `aria-labelledby` as this may override the content of your `<asides>` on some screen readers. Do you not want `aria-describedby` instead? Maybe worth a check on a couple of screen readers before you make this change. Sadly I can't comment on the use of `awk` or `sed` but just thought it might be useful info for you.

Comment: As always, consider using an actual HTML parser to manipulate HTML. Regex is a bad fit for handling structured formats.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie. I tested NVDA + Firefox (73.0) using both techniques. I noticed that in both cases, NVDA will read out the ARIA role "complementary". The difference is that aria-labelledby will announce the ID first then the role. With aria-describedby it is the opposite order (role first id second).  Also, when there are multiple <aside> elements with the same role, aria-labelledby has the advantage that NVDA lists the ID (page-#) with the complementary role in the landmarks lists, whereas without it, the landmark list just displays multiple landmarks with the same name (complementary).

Comment: good stuff, like I said was just a check as something I wasn't sure what behaviour you would see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works according to your description:

```
sed '
/aria-describedby="page-/{
h
s/.*\( aria-describedby="page-[0-9]*"\).*/\1/
x
s/ aria-describedby="page-[0-9]*"//
}
/aside role="\(doc-footnote\|complementary\)"/{
G
s/aside\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/aside\2\1/
}' yourfile
```

How it works:

- for each line matching `aria-describedby="page-` it does what is in `{…}`:

  - `h` "saves" the line as it is now by copying it in the hold space (**overwriting whatever is in the hold space**)
  - `s` deletes what is before and after `aria-describedby="page-n"` (`n` is the number; the leading space is left!)
  - `x` swaps hold and pattern spaces: the hold space contains the edited line, the pattern space the original line that we saved with `h`
  - `s` now deletes `aria-describedby="page-n`
- when a line matching either `aside role="doc-footnote"` or `aside role="complementary"` is hit, the following is done:

  - `G` appends the content of the pattern space to the current line, with a `\n` in between
  - `s` reorder the pieces while removing the `\n`

Comment: Thank you for the solution and for the thorough explanation. Much appreciated.